# Unable to convert a series into dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, series

My function takes a data frame as an argument that represent home adverts from the website. I am counting flats by the number of rooms and receive series which I would like to convert into a dictionary. My `rooms counter` seems to be a series still after applying `to_dict()`. Tried also with `collections` but it is the same.

```
def most_common_room_number(dane):
    rooms = dane['Rooms']
    rooms_counter = rooms.value_counts()
    rooms_counter.to_dict()
    # rooms_counter.to_dict(OrderedDict)
    # dd = defaultdict(list)
    # rooms_counter.to_dict(dd)
    print(rooms_counter)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign `rooms_counter.to_dict()` to a variable and return that variable.

```
series = pd.Series([1, 2, 3])
d = series.to_dict()
print(type(d))
```